# How do I add grip to concrete sealer after it is already applied?

Tags: concrete, driveway, sealant

Last fall, we had H&C Colortop Solvent Based Concreat Sealer 250 applied to a textured concrete driveway and walkway. It look amazingly better and have gotten many complements from the neighbors, but now we are finding out that when it is even slightly moist, it gets incredibly slick. At times, it is almost like walking on ice. What is the best way to add grip to this surface?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to reapply the product (or another compatible sealer) and apply grit to it as an admix.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was kind of afraid of. I guess I won't have to be quite as careful about edges and cracks if I match the color. I have seen some clear coat options but I doubt they would last as long as the coating